# JS - then and waiting for a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

A common topic I know however I just want to confirm my understanding on the world of JS and promises.

So i have the following segment of code that is failing in that the `then` block doesn't actually wait for the segment above to be finished. Namely I'm not getting the final/correct value of `okCheck`.

```
var okCheck = false;

User.findOne({publicID: id}, function (err, userInfo) {
      if ( userInfo.checked.indexOf(id) > -1 ){
        okCheck = true;
      }
})
.then(function() {
      //do some additional stuff using the boolean okCheck
}
```

So to fix this - from what I understand I need to use a `return` - is this correct?

```
var okCheck = false;

User.findOne({publicID: id}, function (err, userInfo) {
      if ( userInfo.checked.indexOf(id) > -1 ){
        okCheck = true;
      }
      return okCheck;
})
.then(function() {
      //do some additional stuff using the boolean okCheck
}
```

Is this correct - namely am i guaranteed that I'll always have the final value of okCheck?

Thanks.

Comment: The `findOne` function looks weird: from your code, it would appear to take a callback argument **and** return a promise. Both mechanisms serve roughly the same purpose, you'd expect the function to either use callbacks **or** promises. Are you sure you're calling it correctly? Can you verify that both your callback and your `then` handler get called (e.g. by adding a `console.log()` call inside those)?

Comment: Thats fine - I've used a console.log to check that. I'm thinking the answer below looks good - what do you think>

Comment: From looking at the answers, it turns out that this particular `findOne` function is [part of Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-one). It would have been much more clear if you mentioned what libraries you were using, so others don't have to guess what functions your code is using. ;-)

Comment: Where is `User.findOne()` documented? If a method takes a callback *and* is thenable, it is far more normal to use *one* of these interfaces, not both. ..... Thanks @MattiasBuelens, you possibly answered my question before I asked it.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand I need to use a `return` - is this correct?

Yes. But `return`ing a value doesn't influence anything timing-related.

The point is that the value you `return` from a `then` callback will be the resolution value of the promise that it returns, and become the argument of the next callback in the chain.

You should not modify outer-scope variables from asynchronous callbacks. The right approach is to defer actions until the promise has resolved, not to "wait" with anything for a variable value to appear:

```
// no `var` here!
User.findOne({publicID: id}).then(function(userInfo) {
    return userInfo.checked.indexOf(id) > -1;
//  ^^^^^^ return a boolean
}).then(function(okCheck) {
//               ^^^^^^^ receive it here as a parameter
    … // do some additional stuff using it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points :

- `okCheck` cannot be reliably used outside the context of User.findOne's callback or a chained .then's callback, therefore there's no benefit in having it as an outer var, in fact it is bad practice to do so.
- You shouldn't be trying to use both a direct callback *and* a chained `then()` - they are alternatives.

Assuming this to be Mongoose, and `userInfo.checked.indexOf()` to be synchronous, you can write either of the following :

**Pass a callback to `User.findOne()`**

```
User.findOne({publicID: id}, function(err, userInfo) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if (userInfo.checked.indexOf(id) > -1) {
            // do additional stuff
        } else {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
});
```

**Chain `.then()` to the promise returned by `User.findOne().exec()`**

```
User.findOne({publicID: id}}).exec().then(function(userInfo) {
    if(userInfo.checked.indexOf(id) > -1) {
        // do additional stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note: Much of this still applies, even if it's not Mongoose.

Answer (score -1):

This is no way how it works, you must return promise in order to use ".then()".

```
var okCheck = false;

User.findOne({publicID: id}).exec()
.then(function (userInfo) {
    if ( userInfo.checked.indexOf(id) > -1 ){
      okCheck = true;
    }
    return okCheck
})
.then(function (okCheck) {
  //do some additional stuff using the boolean okCheck
})
```

Here ".exec()" returns promise.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for the `new Promise()` you are using inside the `.then()` handler.  You can just return a value inside a `.then()` handler and that becomes the resolved value of the current promise.

Comment: So using the code I have above in my question `return okCheck` is ok in itself?

Comment: What do others think of the above now - makes sense to me??

Comment: A small nitpicking: you no longer need the `okCheck` to be declared in the outer scope: it can be scoped inside the first `then` handler. This also forces you to get the result in the second `then` handler from the passed argument rather than from the outer scope.